# How join date with list of many big files in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have such dataframe( sorry i can't understand why numeric columns are character defined. Is there way to convert it to numeric?)

```
chemical=structure(list(п.їHeat = c(21358304L, 21637528L, 21726936L, 21732436L, 
21732964L, 21734988L, 21751532L, 21759760L, 21759760L, 21759760L
), SampleID = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), AnalysisDate = c("2019-10-17 22:18:09", 
"2019-09-17 18:40:47", "2019-09-19 02:48:54", "2019-09-24 22:11:48", 
"2019-09-25 12:50:33", "2019-09-28 03:44:25", "2019-10-15 02:07:25", 
"2019-09-06 23:19:22", "2019-09-07 00:13:30", "2019-09-07 00:30:20"
), TypeTest = c("K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", 
"K"), ValC = c("0.161", "0.286", "0.041", "0.103", "0.193", "0.228", 
"0.194", "0.256", "0.294", "0.293"), ValSi = c("0.195", "0.26", 
"0.002", "0.132", "0.096", "0.194", "0.074", "0.198", "0.169", 
"0.194"), ValMn = c("0.369", "1.17", "0.265", "0.288", "0.436", 
"0.413", "0.479", "0.96", "0.98", "1.0"), ValS = c("0.011", "0.008", 
"0.01", "0.018", "0.018", "0.019", "0.022", "0.019", "0.014", 
"0.013"), ValP = c("0.029", "0.019", "0.008", "0.019", "0.014", 
"0.018", "0.028", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02"), ValCr = c("0.046", 
"0.05", "0.029", "0.032", "0.033", "0.036", "0.04", "0.045", 
"0.046", "0.047"), ValNi = c("0.027", "0.033", "0.025", "0.023", 
"0.025", "0.029", "0.026", "0.027", "0.027", "0.027"), ValCu = c("0.043", 
"0.06", "0.04", "0.039", "0.043", "0.035", "0.05", "0.043", "0.042", 
"0.042"), ValAs = c("0.002", "0.002", "0.002", "0.002", "0.002", 
"0.002", "0.002", "0.002", "0.002", "0.002"), ValN = c("0.006", 
"0.006", "0.005", "0.004", "0.004", "0.005", "0.007", "0.008", 
"0.008", "0.008"), ValAl = c("0.042", "0.011", "0.047", "0.005", 
"0.002", "0.007", "0.003", "0.001", "0.003", "0.002"), ValTi = c("0.003", 
"0.004", "0.001", "0.001", "0.0", "0.002", "0.0", "0.001", "0.002", 
"0.002"), ValSn = c("0.001", "0.003", "0.002", "0.001", "0.002", 
"0.001", "0.002", "0.001", "0.001", "0.001"), ValV = c("0.007", 
"0.046", "0.001", "0.005", "0.001", "0.001", "0.007", "0.002", 
"0.002", "0.002"), ValMo = c("0.001", "0.002", "0.001", "0.001", 
"0.001", "0.001", "0.001", "0.002", "0.002", "0.002"), ValCa = c("0.0002", 
"0.0001", "0.0001", "0.0002", "0.0001", "0.0001", "0.0005", "0.0001", 
"0.0005", "0.0005"), ValAls = c("0.041", "0.011", "0.046", "0.004", 
"0.002", "0.005", "0.002", "0.001", "0.002", "0.002")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also i have 280 files with data.

```
dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrTotalCastingLength_8.csv
dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPosFilteredDeviation_8.csv
dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPosFiltered_8.csv
dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPos_8.csv
dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrPR2Press_8.csv
dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStatus_8.csv
dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrPR1Press_8.csv
    ...
```

It has such format

```
T                   V
03.09.2019 17:36    0
03.09.2019 20:35    0
03.09.2019 23:34    0
04.09.2019 2:33     0
04.09.2019 5:32     0
04.09.2019 8:31     0
04.09.2019 11:30    0
```

chemical join with it by key fields `AnalysisDate = T (columns)` (It is date column)

How can i merge all 280 dataframes to chemical that names of files was in colname instead `V`

for example after joining with `dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrTotalCastingLength_8.csv` instead V must be STR_PLC8#StrTotalCastingLength_8
like this
[image: ...]

Is there the way to do it not manually? I don't want each files merge such

`1.` merge dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrTotalCastingLength_8.csv with chemical
`then` dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPosFilteredDeviation_8.csv with chemical
and so on.
I want indicate path`(C:/Myfiles)` to folder with these 280 files and then all these files must be joined with chemical data frame automatically.
How do that. In final chemical dataset must added 280 columns with the names of csv files and not just V.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, this should work (assuming your csv paths are in a vector `csv_paths` and the chemical dataframe `chemical`).

```r
library(tidyverse)

## coerce AnalysisDate into actual date
.chemical <- mutate(chemical, AnalysisDate = as.Date(AnalysisDate))

join_chemical <- function(path) {
  read.csv(path) %>%
    ## rename T and V columns (assuming they are always in this order)
    magrittr::set_colnames(c("AnalysisDate", basename(path))) %>%
    ## convert AnalysisDate to actual date (assuming format is consistent)
    mutate(AnalysisDate = as.Date(AnalysisDate, format = "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M")) %>%
    left_join(.chemical, by = "AnalysisDate")
}

joined_dfs <- map(csv_paths, join_chemical)
```

This will give you a list of dataframes where `chemical` and any given csv file are joined by their respective `date` columns, with the `V` column renamed appropriately.

You didn't specify what kind of join you wanted or what should happen in the case of a mismatch/missing date. In the code I gave (left join) any dates are missing in `chemical` that are in one of the csv files will produce a bunch of `NA`s in the other columns. This is what happens if I test the code using the date you provided, as none of the dates match.

Also, if you want to make the char columns numeric, do something like `mutate(chemical, across(contains("Val"), as.numeric))` which will convert all the columns with 'Val' to number-like (the only reason I can think why they wouldn't be numeric to begin with is because at least one row isn't a number).

Answer (score 1):

This will build a list `df` of data frames containing all lines from the chemical data frame where the Analysis Date, hour and minute was found in the content of the files from the file directory. It also stores the file name in column V.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

#convert chemical columns to numeric
chemical[,-c(1:4)] <- apply(chemical[,-c(1:4)],2,as.numeric)

setwd("C:/Myfiles")
files <- list.files()
chemical$AnalysisDate  <- ymd_hms(chemical$AnalysisDate)

df <- lapply(files, function(i) {
   #assuming the file content is separated by tabs
   f <- read.csv2(i, header=T, sep='\t') %>% mutate(T = dmy_hm(T))
   f %>% mutate(j = date(T), V = i) %>%
    inner_join(chemical %>% mutate(j = date(AnalysisDate)))
})
```